# Dúvida - Insert tabela SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, query, sql-insert, sql-server-2012

preciso inserir algumas informações na tabela chamada tarefa, porém, somente quando uma determinada condição for aceita que no caso são esses dois campos de data, eu coloquei pra hoje por exemplo caso fosse manual, ou seja, iria inserir no sistema na data de hoje, mas só quero q seja inserida na tabela quando essas datas forem por exemplo pro dia 20 desse mes.

```
insert into Tarefa
(
    TarID,
    ProID,  
    TarData ,
    DataAberturaSistema 
)
values (
    168442,
    2,
    '2017-10-05 09:20:10.000',  
    '2017-10-05 09:20:10.015'
)
```

Comment: você pode usar uma trigger para rejeitar as inserções que não respeitem as regras

Comment: e como seria mais ou menos essa trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará criar uma trigger, no corpo da trigger você trabalhará os valores inseridos fazendo a validação:

**Exemplo Basico de trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_VENDAS_AI
ON VENDAS
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @VALOR  DECIMAL(10,2),
    @DATA   DATETIME

SELECT @DATA = DATA, @VALOR = VALOR FROM INSERTED

UPDATE CAIXA SET SALDO_FINAL = SALDO_FINAL + @VALOR
WHERE DATA = @DATA

END
GO
```

Considerando as tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE CAIXA
(
    DATA            DATETIME,
    SALDO_INICIAL   DECIMAL(10,2),
    SALDO_FINAL     DECIMAL(10,2)
)
GO

INSERT INTO CAIXA
VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103)), 100, 100)
GO

CREATE TABLE VENDAS
(
    DATA    DATETIME,
    CODIGO  INT,
    VALOR   DECIMAL(10,2)
)
GO
```

Aê basta receber os valores na chamada da trigger e tratar sua regra.

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/triggers-no-sql-server-teoria-e-pratica-aplicada-em-uma-situacao-real/28194